Use app service to provide upload credentials for javascript upload to OneDrive
We have been uploading files to OneDrive using JQuery and Ajax to send the file to an app server that uses the Graph API to upload to a OneDrive that does not belong to the end user. The App server has full rights to this OneDrive, but the individual uploading does not and must not. This means that the file is transferred from client to app server, then app server to OneDrive which seems a very poor use of resources likely reducing performance. Also, some (Mac) users are getting “connection unexpectedly dropped by the server” at peak times.
Is it possible for the user to call an API which causes the app server to generate limited upload credentials in C# (using the Graph API), then return these to the client so that the file can be uploaded directly from the client to OneDrive? These credentials would need to be limited to uploading this one file and not risk users hacking client-side code to get wider access to the destination OneDrive.

This sounds like a tremendously bad idea. Anything you put in your client application will be read by users. Even if you could get Microsoft to give you an access token that's only valid for a single file upload, you don't want to give that to your client - it's not theirs to use. Have your backend API upload the file to OneDrive. Have the client give the file to upload to the backend API.

Thanks @gunr2171 so it's best to keep with the current method and accept the overhead on the app server. In which case we'll have to work out why mac clients are being dropped by the server.
